# Generating ctags for vim omnicpp does not work?

Tags: vim, terminal, ctags

i want to have Code complention in Vim. I try it using this tutorial: http://design.liberta.co.za/articles/code-completion-intellisense-for-cpp-in-vim-with-omnicppcomplete/

my problem:

this terminal prompt should be generate a "tags" file in the direcoty, but it seems that the flags are not right?

```
$ ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q ./
```

If i use this in terminal i get this.

```
usage: ctags [flags] filenames...
    -Dword  Ignore "word" -- handy for parameter macro name
    -F      Use /regexp/ (default)
    -B      Use ?regexp? instead of /regexp/
    -N      Use line numbers instead of /regexp/
    -g      Store static tags as though they were global (implies -h -s)
    -s      Include static tags
    -e      Include extern tags
    -i      Include inline definitions
    -t      Include typedefs
    -v      Include variable declarations
    -h      Add hints to help elvis distinguish between overloaded tags
    -l      Add a "ln" line number hint (implies -h)
    -p      Write parse info to stdout (for debugging ctags)
    -d      Warn about duplicates, on stdout
    -x      Write cross-reference table to stdout; skip "tags"
    -r      Write a "refs" file, in addition to "tags"
    -a      Append to "tags", instead of overwriting
If no flags are given, ctags assumes it should use -l -i -s -t -v
Report bugs to kirkenda@cs.pdx.edu
```

Do i make sth. wrong? This alredy the second tutorial i read and i always failing on this step.

best regards

Comment: I create my `tags` file with exactly the same arguments and it works flawlessly. What version of `ctags` do you use!?

Comment: Oh god ~~ i forget that i install ctags from elvis-tools a long time ago .... thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/). You should install it.

`ctags --help` output should start with something like the following

```
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: May 22 2012, 13:52:32
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex
```